# Gradle: mystery class file appearing

Tags: java, jar, gradle

In our project, we have a gradle build file pointing to the src directory. There are a few internal jar files sitting in a lib directory that gradle points to with the fileTree method in dependencies. I built these jar files to include the source code. Most of these jar files contain the schemas and stubs for calling webservices (generated with wsimport) and part of their build involves packaging the associated WSDL in the classes directory with the Service and Port method.

What I am seeing is, when I execute my build, one of the WSImport Service classes is being compiled **out of the jar file** and copied along with the class files in my source directory. I have no idea why this specific file would be targeted and compiled.

As I mentioned earlier, this class does refer to a WSDL file that is placed in the same package as the Service.class and is referred to by the following:

```
url = com.addresses.ws.addressvalidation.AddressValidationService.class.getResource("AddressValidationService.wsdl");
```

but one other webservice we are using does the same thing and isn't compiled. The code that uses this class is fairly unremarkable:

```
AddressValidationService service = new AddressValidationService();
AddressValidationPortType portType = service.getAddressValidationServicePort();
```

And the excerpt from build.gradle that refers to the directory containing the jar files:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile fileTree('webapp/WEB-INF/lib')
}
```

So my apologies if the information here is not detailed enough, I just have no idea why this might be happening so I'm not sure what other information I should include.

Comment: BTW: I should mention that if I delete the java files out of the address validation jar, this problem does not happen anymore.

Comment: javac will compile source files in Jars by default. See javac docs for how to turn this off, then configure `JavaCompile` tasks accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but this still doesn't explain why this one particular file is being compiled/distributed

Comment: I don't know what the exact rules are around whether source files on the compile class path get compiled (check the javac docs), but the solution will likely stay the same (configure javac not to compile any sources found on the compile class path). Or even better, package sources as a separate Jar.